# How to manually cross fold evaluate naive bayes in weka?

Tags: java, weka

I'm using an own bag of word model instead of wekas StringToWordVector (turns out to be a mistake, but as it's only a school project, I'd like to finish it with my approach), so I cannot use it's CrossFoldEvaluation, as my BoW dictionary would contain the words of the training data too.

```
for (int n = 0; n < folds; n++) {
   List<String> allData = getAllReviews(); // 2000 reviews
   List<String> trainingData = getTrainingReviews(n, folds); // random 1800 reviews
   List<String> testData = getTestReviews(n, folds); // random 200 reviews

   bagOfWordsModel.train(trainingData);  //  builds a vocabulary of 1800 training reviews
   Instances inst = bagOfWordsModel.vectorize(allData); // returns 1800 instances with the class attribute set to positive or negative, and 200 without 

   // todo: evaluate
   Classifier cModel = (Classifier) new NaiveBayes();
   cModel.buildClassifier(inst);

   Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(inst);
   eTest.evaluateModel(cModel, inst);

   // print results
   String strSummary = eTest.toSummaryString();
   System.out.println(strSummary);
}
```

How can I now evaluate this? I thought, weka will automatically try to determine the class attribute of the instances that have no value for the class attribute. But instead, it tells me  `weka.filters.supervised.attribute.Discretize: Cannot handle missing class values!`

Comment: You want to train the model then evaluate it on unknown data? Cross-fold validation would require a known class label as you can't train on unknown data.

Comment: Hmm, but if I assign a class label to the test data, how can wekas Evaluation distinguish between test- and training data? Remember I cannot use wekas built in CrossFold evaluation

Comment: If you have a test set, you won't want to be using cross-fold validation anyway - [What is cross-fold validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). Are you able to train the model without an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have both a training set and a testing set, you should train the classifier on the training data, which should be labelled, and then use the trained model to classify the unlabeled test data.

```
Classifier cModel = new NaiveBayes();
cModel.buildClassifier(trainingData);
```

And then, with the use of the following line you should be able to classify an unknown instance and get a prediction:

```
double clsLabel = cModel.classifyInstance(testData.instance(0));
```

Or you could use the [Evaluation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModel-weka.classifiers.Classifier-weka.core.Instances-java.lang.Object...-) class to make predictions on the entire test set.

```
Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation();
evaluation.evaluateModel(cModel, testData);
```

You have pointed out that you are attempting to implement your own cross-validation by taking a random subset of the data - There is a method that does k-fold cross-validation for you int he Evaluation class ([crossValidateModel](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#crossValidateModel-java.lang.String-weka.core.Instances-int-java.lang.String:A-java.util.Random-)).

```
 Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(trainingData);
 evaluation.crossValidateModel(cModel, trainingData, 10, new Random(1));
```

**Note:** Cross-validation is used when you don't have a test set by taking a subset of the training data and holding it out of training and using that to evaluate performance [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

K-fold cross-validation splits the training data into K subsets. It puts one of the subsets aside and uses the remaining to train the classifier, returning to the subset set aside to evaluate the model. It then repeats this process until it has used each subset as the test set.

Comment: I'm going to try it out, thank you. PS. I'm actually also not having a particular test set; I just use 1/10th of the 2000 labled reviews as a test set, so basically I'm trying to build my own k-fold cross validation.

Comment: @user66875 That would be 10% cross-validation. k-fold cross validation would be segmenting into k subsets and use every segmented subset as the testing set while the other k-1 sets are used to evaluate (I'll add that to the answer).

Comment: Regarding your note: Unfortunately I cannot let weka partition the data, because I have already built my BagOfWord model with my own partition of the reviews. That is my initial problem. If I build the dictionary with the word occurrences  (BagOfWord) with all 2000 reviews, that seems like some kind of cheating to me. I don't think the model should learn about the content of the 200 test reviews. Or maybe I misunderstand something.

Comment: @user66875 That's fair. The k-fold cross-validation would normally reapply the filter used to make the bag of words for each iteration. I was just noting the difference, if the performance offered by traditional cross-validation is appropriate the method you are using *should* be fine. Though, as it's a school project I highly suspect the method you have taken is already overboard as it is.

Answer (score 0):

When Training, only Input the instances with set class.

In this line:

```
cModel.buildClassifier(inst);
```

you are Training a naive Bayes classifier. Input only the training examples(!). Evaluate against all data (with labels!). Evaluation checks the predicted Label against the actual Label, if I remember correctly.

The 200 data points without class Label seem useless, what are they for?

Comment: Evaluate against all data or maybe better just the test data.

Comment: ok so I build the classifier with only the training instances, and then use `Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(inst);
   eTest.evaluateModel(cModel, inst);` with all 2000?

Comment: @user66875 now that I think about it, probably with the 200 test examples, not the 2000 complete set. Assuming you have the Labels for These, too.